# Remote Desktop Client Crashes following domain join

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-domain

I recently joined my laptop to our windows domain and now the remote desktop client crashes when i try and connect to any machine. It works if I run as administrator but not ordinarily.

The domain join migrated my local profile to the domain profile which i think is where the problem lies.

I'm guessing its a permission thing as I had a similar problem with dropbox and had to delete reg keys and reinstall. I can't figure out how to fix this problem though.

The event viewer shows this:

> Faulting application name: mstsc.exe, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7ab44
>
> Faulting module name: FACredProv2.dll, version: 2.4.95.1, time stamp: 0x4bb8d766
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Fault offset: 0x00000000000025b2
>
> Faulting process id: 0xb24
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cd43fbd3a81fba
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\FACredProv2.dll
>
> Report Id: 154ee55a-afef-11e1-a443-b8ac6f704c5d

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the dell face recognition software.

The domain join caused a few apps (dropbox, saleforce sync) to crash. uninstalling and reinstalling each of these apps solved it.  I didn't realise it was the dell software since i was using remote desktop, must have some hook into all authentication dialogues even when it isn't an option.